# Trying to integrate Javascript range slider into my website but not sure where to start

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a little test shell for my website using Javascript. What I have at the moment is a normal website. PHP/HTML with an SQL backend.

What I'd like is a simple Javascript feature whereby the user has a single slider object and can use this object to set the upper and lower limit on a number of variables, which will be determined by a drop down box just underneath the slider.

Aside from this, I'd just like a number of checkboxes which dictate which products are displayed (i.e if I'd like food but not drink, the food checkbox would be ticked!).

I'm not expecting anyone on SO to do this for me, of course, but I would like to find some specific areas I could go to learn how to do this, and google is failing me in this regard. I will then begin working/editing this post to show my code/ask for help.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to build a specific search for site, but instead of the user searching it is what is displayed. I would start with looking at php, based upon which checkboxes they choose, you can return variables which would show them what they want to see.

I personally wouldn't use javascipt for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your level of experience is with Javascript, so my apologies if this answer is too basic.

To put a slider on your page refer here for the HTML:
http://webhole.net/2010/04/24/html-5-slider-input-tutorial/

Then in Javascript get the value of that slider when making your GET requests of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected value or checked value in the target element, when you process, you just call the element and get the value from them. Using jquery data() method can store the value to element and retrive it pretty easy.

If you still have no clue, I redcomend you learn some basic javscript techniques, go to this site www.jquery.com .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [jQuery](http://jquery.org) and jQuery UI? jQuery UI has a nice slider widget with a number of configuration options and good documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

If you're not used to it, there may be a bit of a learning curve for jQuery, but it makes a great number of UI features much, much easier to code. Showing and hiding elements based on checkboxes, for example, is a pain to do in straight JS but fairly simple to do with jQuery. There are lots of other ways to just make a slider, but if you're planning to do much more with the UI I'd strongly recommend using a library like jQuery to do the heavy lifting.